# I'm having trouble designing the best logic for a "guestroom" style table for temporary nonregistered users in my Angular App

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, database-design

I am building an application that has registered users, and those users have a link that they can share with non registered guests. I am trying to create a list of guests that waiting to enter the "room" of the page but I am stuck trying to think of the best way to do that. 
Currently when a guest signs in I register the guest in the db and the registered user then sees the guest list via an observable connected to that table. Then the registered user can click a button corresponding to that user and start engaging with them. The problems i am forseeing is 
How do I clear that entry if a guest closes out of the app? 
How do I clear all of those entries for the next time the registered user logs in?

I've spent the last two days trying to solve this but I feel like there might be a better solution for this so if anyone has any ideas or tips I'd love some help!

Comment: It's hard to be certain without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces what you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I have a feeling part of what you're looking for may be solved by using an `onDisconnect()` handler. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works

Comment: Thank you for that guidance Frank that is exactlly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write (create, delete, modify) a value when the client disconnects from the server, you'll want to use an `onDisconnect()` handler. These are write operations that you send to the server when you *do* have a connection, that the server then executes when it detects that the client is gone.

A thing to keep in mind when using `onDisconnect()` handlers is that there are two ways of disconnecting:

- a clean disconnect, in which case the client informs the server that is disconnecting. In this case the server immediately executes the `onDisconnect` handler.
- a dirty disconnect, which happens when the client disconnects without informing the server. In this case it may take a few minutes before the server detects that the client is gone.